# Different behavior between Restsharp and cURL

Tags: curl, restsharp

I'm trying to get data from tumblr.

With RestSharp:

```
var Address = "https://[any].tumblr.com/api/read/json?filter=text&type=photo&num=50&start=1";
var Client = new RestClient(Address);
var Request = new RestRequest();
var R = Client.Execute(Request);
```

I get back a 200, empty content and a redirect url that points to a page with gdpr/advertisers, etc stuff.

The same Url in the browser has the exact same outcome.
Accessing it with wget does the same.

With cUrl:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://[any].tumblr.com/api/read/json?type=photo&num=50&start=1"
```

I get the proper content.

How comes?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to understand:

Tumblr handles the request differently if 'curl' is present in the user-agent string...

Just by adding:

```
Request.AddHeader("user-agent", "curl/7.54.0");
```

to the restsharp request solved the problem...